# A group scheme whose reduced underlying scheme is not normal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, examples-counterexamples, group-schemes

Let $G$ be a group scheme over a perfect field $k$. Let $G_{red} \hookrightarrow G$ be the reduced underlying scheme. It can be shown that $G_{red}$ is a closed subgroup scheme of $G$. Is there an example where $G_{red}$ is not a normal subgroup scheme of $G$?

I saw this in an exercise of a book I'm reading, and just can't think of any example.

Comment: Was the exercise to find an example, or did it ask whether it was true?

Comment: The exercise is to find an example.